# Active Record belongs_to association not adding foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, associations

I have a nested resource with 'posts' containing many 'comments' and associations set up between these models. But when I create a comment for a post the 'post_id' in the comments table remains empty and no link is established. The comment text itself gets created ok.

I'm using Rails ver 4.2.1 and a postgresql database.

The associations are set up like this:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
end
```

This is the route set up:

resources :posts do
    resources :comments
  end

I create the comments from the comments/new view with this code:

```
= form_for [@post, @comment] do |f|
  = f.label :comment
  = f.text_field :comment
  = f.submit "Add Comment"
```

My comments controller is like this:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = Comment.new
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = Comment.create(comment_params)
    redirect_to posts_path
  end

  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:comment)
  end

end
```

I have the column 'post_id' set up in the comments table and my schema is this:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150404204033) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "comments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "comment"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer  "post_id"
  end

  add_index "comments", ["post_id"], name: "index_comments_on_post_id", using: :btree

  create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  add_foreign_key "comments", "posts"
end
```

Just can't work out what is going on, I've used almost identical code on another project and that worked.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code:

```
 def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = Comment.create(comment_params)
    redirect_to posts_path
 end
```

you find the post but never do anything with it. The comment has no knowledge of that post. You need to set comment's post to `@post`.